# HTML dl tag .. definition list or description list?

Tags: html

Which word is dl tag short for HTML tags?

I thought it was a definition list so far, but is the description list the answer?

1.dl tag -> definition list
2.dl tag -> description list

Which one is more correct? 1 or 2?

Comment: It was originally definition list and was then changed to description. Changed occurred during HTML 4 to 5

Comment: @ j08691 What I wanted to know was this. I obviously knew it was a definition list, but I was confused because mdn is a description list. thank you for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dl` element is "Description List element"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

[w3 definition](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/deflists.html)